# Angular $timeout ou Javascript timeout?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout

Eu sou iniciante no Angular JS. Percebi que temos um serviço no Angular chamado de `$timeout`.

Fiquei curioso para entender o por quê de existir esse serviço, já que nativamente o Javascript possui o `setTimeout`.

Qual é a diferença entre o `$timeout` e o `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$timeout` automaticamente executa `$scope.$apply()` após a execução do *callback*, propagando assim toda e qualquer alteração no modelo realizada pelo *callback*.

`$timeout` também fornece, como retorno de chamada, uma *promise*.

Comment: A dúvida principal é: Se eu usar `setTimeout`, ocorre o risco de um dado não ser atualizado no angular. Pensei que esse fosse o motivo, mas vejo que é muito mais.

Answer (score 0):

"A ideia é basicamente a mesma", inclusive na documentação é dito que `$timeout` é um wrapper de `window.setTimeout`. A vantagem de usar `$timeout` é que ele serve como uma `Promise`, assim evita os `Callback Hell` caso precise encadear comportamento após o tempo esperado. Também tem a vantagem de por ser um "serviço injetado" ele pode ser substituído facilmente por outra implementação.